# Why am I getting "argument of type char is incompatible with parameter of type FILE"?

Tags: c++, char

What could be a possible replacement for that?

I do not know what to change it to.

```c
bool File_Exits(char fileName[]) {

    FILE* fp = fopen_s(fileName, "r");
    if (fp) {
        fclose(fp);
        return true;
    }
    return errno != ENOENT;
}

bool isFileCanBeRead(char fileName[]) {
    FILE* fp = fopen_s(fileName, "r");
    if (fp) {
        fclose(fp);
        return true;
    }
    return errno != ENOENT && errno != EPERM;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This includes the full error message.

Comment: Read [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019).

Comment: `fopen_s` does not return a `FILE *`, and it takes in three parameters. Documentation MikeCAT linked above explains this.

Comment: Maybe it should be `FILE *fp = std::fopen(fileName, "r");` instead?

Answer (score 4):

See the definition of `fopen_s` in this reference:

[fopen_s, _wfopen_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019).

```
errno_t fopen_s(
   FILE** pFile,
   const char *filename,
   const char *mode
);
```

Try this instead:

```
FILE *fp = nullptr;
errno_t openResult = fopen_s(&fp, filename, "r");
```